# jquery inside a while statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a drop down menu that shows more information about each person displayed when the person is clicked on.

```
//Get users information             
$sql = "SELECT user.uid, user.first, user.last, user.email, user.rating  
        FROM user 
        INNER JOIN team_members ON user.uid=team_members.uid
        WHERE tid = '$tid'
        ORDER BY user.last ASC";            

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        //name as button(displayed on page load)
        echo "<button class='player' type='submit'>
            ".$row["first"]." ".$row["last"]."</button><br>";

        //hidden information to be shown once button clicked
        echo "<div class='player_info' style='display:none'>
               ".$row["email"]." ".$row["rating"]."  
              </div>";
    }  


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.player').click(function(){
        $('div.player_info').toggle();
    });
});
```

The issue I am having is that when clicked it displays all information in each loop. So if there are 5 people and you click one name, each person populates information. The information corresponds to each person but I only want to show the info of the person clicked.

I thought this would mean that I need to somehow uniquely identify each class but cant seem to figure it out and make it work. Or maybe there is a better way to run my loop to solve the problem. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you `echo $tid` what do you get?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Maybe it's time to look into js frameworks

Comment: Tadman, thank you for the information. I just started messing around with this stuff so any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML `data-` attributes to correlate each `button` to a `div`.  Then modify the JavaScript to use the embedded data.

In the below snippet, I added `data-uid` attributes to both the `button` and the `div` that are populated with the `uid` from the database.

When the `button` is clicked, the `data-uid` is read and used to select the `div` with corresponding `data-uid`.

Another small improvement that I made was to change the `type` attribute on the `button` to `button`.  A value of `submit` means that the button should be used for submit a form which is not what you are doing here.

```
//Get users information             
$sql = "SELECT user.uid, user.first, user.last, user.email, user.rating  
        FROM user 
        INNER JOIN team_members ON user.uid=team_members.uid
        WHERE tid = '$tid'
        ORDER BY user.last ASC";            

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        //name as button(displayed on page load)
        echo "<button class='player' type='button' data-uid='".$row["uid"]."'>
            ".$row["first"]." ".$row["last"]."</button><br>";

        //hidden information to be shown once button clicked
        echo "<div class='player_info' style='display:none' data-uid='".$row["uid"]."'>
               ".$row["email"]." ".$row["rating"]."  
              </div>";
    }  


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.player').click(function(){
        $('div.player_info[data-uid='+$(this).attr('data-uid')+']').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest you provide details of what changes you made

Comment: Super dig this answer btw

Comment: This works perfectly. I figured there must be a way to uniquely identify each, but I didn't think to use the $uid. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `.player` and `.player_info` in a `<div>` and do some toggling with JQuery like so:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "<div class='player-container'>

        //name as button(displayed on page load)
        echo "<button class='player' type='submit'>
            ".$row["first"]." ".$row["last"]."</button><br>";

        //hidden information to be shown once button clicked
        echo "<div class='player_info' style='display:none'>
               ".$row["email"]." ".$row["rating"]."  
              </div>";

        echo "</div>
    }  


$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide all of the player_info containers
    $(".player_info").hide();

    $(".player-container").click(function() {

        // this selects any child element of the clicked container with the 
        // classname .player_info and toggles it open or closed
        $(this).children(".player_info").slideToggle();

    });

});
```

Comment: Wrapping each result in a `div` container is a good way to go as well... The JS could be modified to do something like this: `$('button.player').click(function(){ $(this).closest(".player-container").find(".player_info").toggle(); });`.  The idea being traverse up the DOM from the clicked button until you find the parent with the `player-container` class, then find it's child with the `player_info` class.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't specifying which player_info you want to toggle, `$('div.player_info')` will select all of them. A quick and dirty way to solve this would be to use select the next sibling with jQuery, relative to the button, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.player').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Not the best idea. I see where you're coming from, but if anybody were to alter the ```html```, you'd be screwed.

Comment: Hence the quick and dirty solution